# write zero to blank cells python

Tags: python, csv

I have a few data files contained flow data. For example,

```
9/12/1999   0   
13/12/1999  2544    
14/12/1999  2552    
15/12/1999      
16/12/1999          
18/12/1999  3039    
19/12/1999  3043
```

I wrote a code to read all data files and write to a new output file which has the format
Date Flow1 Flow2 etc.

I also wrote it in consecutive date (where there is no data for that date, write 0 to the output file). I don't include that bit here in the script below.

The issue I have is that when there is a line with date but no flow data in the data files (for eg. line 4, 5 in the above example). The code gives me blank value for that line instead of 0. I thought it is a simple thing but I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help me with that?
My code is

```
for Qfilename in Q_filenamelist:
    Qfileopen = open(Qfilename,'r')
    for line in Qfileopen:
        line = line.rstrip()        
        if not line.startswith("and") and not line.startswith("Time") and not line.startswith("Date"):      #ignore headers
            Qwordslist = line.split(',')
            time = Qwordslist[0]
            flow = Qwordslist[1]
            if not time in time_list:
                time_list.append(time)
            index = time+" "+Qfilename
            Qourdict[index] = flow            

    Qfileopen.close()           
time_list.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y'))
#write output data
outfile = open(outfilename,'w')
outfile.write("Date,")
for Qfilename in Q_filenamelist:
    Qfilename = Qfilename.split(".")[0]
    outfile.write(Qfilename+',')
outfile.write('\n')

for time in time_list:
    outfile.write(time+',')
    for Qfilename in Q_filenamelist:
        index = time+" "+Qfilename          
        grabflow = Qourdict.get(index,"0.0")
        if grabflow == " ":
            outfile.write("0.0"+',')
        else:
            outfile.write(str(grabflow)+',')
    outfile.write('\n')
outfile.close()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Unless this is homework, http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, you might try:

```
Qourdict[index] = flow if flow.strip() else '0'
```

Instead of:

```
Qourdict[index] = flow
```

There is not much to go on...